# Do not encapsulate else ifs in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I am trying to use some predefined code styles in PhpStorm, in order to autoformat using `Ctrl+Alt+L`, such as Zend or CodeIgniter.

However, all of them convert a simple

```
if ($a) {
  //
} else if ($b) {
 //
} else if ($c) {
  //
}
```

into

```
if ($a) {
  //
} else {
  if ($b) {
    //
  } else {
    if ($c) {
      //
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get rid of this? I tried setting options like `Group use => do not wrap` and `Special else if treatment => false`, but these seems not to work.

Codestyle XML: https://pastebin.com/Lu5NMys3

Comment: What happens if you put the else statements on the next line -the same indentation level as the if?

Comment: @pcgben same result

Comment: That is disappointing to say the least.  What about Allman style bracing (which I feel is the standard for php).  Just trying to rule things out.

Comment: @pcgben Actually, Allman bracing is being applied on classes and functions, but not general statements

Comment: @Luiz *"I tried unchecking/changing several options but none worked."* Show options that you have tried. It works just fine here... so you must be trying different options or whatnot.

Comment: @LazyOne I really don't know even what options make sense. I was like a monkey typing, this is why I didnt list this here. I updated with the most "probably meaningful ones".

Comment: @Luiz I was expecting to actually see a screenshot. Giving individual option names is usually not enough (because of possible nuances). But out of those you have mentioned: `Special else if treatment` must be enabled for sure. Even better -- export your code style and share it (Google Drive or alike).

Comment: @Luiz P.S. Why not use `elseif` instead? It seems to be more reliable. That's if you can, of course (code is yours or you can change it).

Comment: @LazyOne I don't care about using `elseif`, if I can get rid of this rule. Updated question with codestyle XML.

Comment: @LazyOne Special elseif treatment worked, although editing to `elseif`. Please submit an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Code Style | PHP`
3. `Wrapping and Braces` tab
4. `'if()' statement --> Special 'else if' treatment` -- ensure that this option is checked.

   [image]
5. `Code Conversion` tab
6. `Convert else if / esleif to:` - either disable or select desired style.

   [image]